# Jquery Bootstrap show and hide span on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Here is my drop down in HTML**

```
<li class="dropdown profile-dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
<span class="hidden-xs">Login</span> <b class="caret"></b>
</a>
<span class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id='topArea'>
<span id='LoginArea'>Login</span>
<span id='RegisterArea'>Register</span>
<br>
<span id='login'>This is Login Area</span>
<span id='register' style='display:none'>This is Register Area</span>
</span>
</li>
```

**Here is my Jquery to Show and Hide Login and Register Area**

```
$("#showLoginArea").click(function(){
    console.log('login');
    $("#login").show();
    $("#register").hide();
});

$("#showRegisterArea").click(function(){
    console.log('register');
    $("#login").hide();
    $("#register").show();
});
```

But Clicking the `showRegisterArea` Span the Entire Menu is getting hide as i used `data-toggle="dropdown"`.

How can i fix this

Note :

While i click the register the register area is shown but the popup hides, and while click the pop again , the register area is being shown.

How can i avoid or override it.

Comment: Might be a typo in the markup, but I don't see an element with Id `loginArea` but two with Id `showLoginArea`

Comment: Please look at your selectors and your `id` attributes. I only see `#registerArea` as having a match.

Comment: @AntonioManente Sorry it was a typo and i have updated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a revised, simplified fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cu3gdgb3/1/

HTML:

```
<li class="dropdown profile-dropdown">

<span class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id='topArea'>
<span id='showLoginArea'>Login</span>
<span id='showRegisterArea'>Register</span>
<br>
<span id='loginArea'>This is Login Area</span>
<span id='registerArea'>This is Register Area</span>
</span>
</li>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#loginArea").hide();
$("#registerArea").hide();
$("#showLoginArea").click(function(){
    console.log('login');
    $("#loginArea").toggle();
    $("#registerArea").hide();
});

$("#showRegisterArea").click(function(){
    console.log('register');
    $("#loginArea").hide();
    $("#registerArea").toggle();
});
```

You were incorrectly referencing the `<div>`'s you wanted to toggle.

EDIT - further to OP's request for login / register areas to hide when any other area of the page is click, see updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cu3gdgb3/2/

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest("#topArea").length === 0) {
        $("#loginArea").hide();
        $("#registerArea").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: @BizDevB, did this answer help with revised fiddle? Please mark answer as correct if it helps you as it will help others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

As mention is comment by @Antonio there was no `loginArea` area fix this here.

```js
$("#showLoginArea").click(function(){
    console.log('login');
    $("#loginArea").show();
    $("#registerArea").hide();
});

$("#showRegisterArea").click(function(){
    console.log('register');
    $("#loginArea").hide();
    $("#registerArea").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="dropdown profile-dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
<span class="hidden-xs">Login</span> <b class="caret"></b>
</a>
<span class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id='topArea'>
<span id='showLoginArea'>Login</span>
<span id='showRegisterArea'>Register</span>
<br>
<span id='loginArea'>This is Login Area</span>
<span id='registerArea' style='display:none'>This is Register Area</span>
</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the event in to the function and stop the propagation or bubbling of the click event so the login dialog doesn't close. Also the naming of the loginArea needs to be changed.

```
<script>
$("#showLoginArea").click(function(event){

    event.stopPropagation();

    $("#loginArea").show();
    $("#registerArea").hide();
});

$("#showRegisterArea").click(function(event){

    event.stopPropagation();

    $("#loginArea").hide();
    $("#registerArea").show();
});</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<li class="dropdown profile-dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
<span class="hidden-xs">Login</span> <b class="caret"></b>
</a>
<span class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id='topArea'>
<span id='showLoginArea'>Login</span>
<span id='showRegisterArea'>Register</span>
<br>
<span id='loginArea'>This is Login Area</span>
<span id='registerArea' style='display:none'>This is Register Area</span>
</span>
</li>
```

Your second loginarea was incorrectly named